# Java storing user preferences

Tags: java, preferences

I'm making a program with a simple GUI, where the user have to do the login before starting use the program.
I want to store username and password and, if the user check the "Remember me" checkbox, i want that he doesn't need to enter data next time.
I tried doing with Java Preferences API, this way:

```
private Preferences prefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());
prefs.put("codCliente", txtCodCliente.getText());
prefs.put("username", txtUsername.getText());
prefs.put("password", DigestUtils.md5Hex(String.valueOf(txtPassword.getPassword())));
```

But if i close and reopen the app, if i print the content of variables, it returns "Null key" NullPointerException.

I tried to save them in a .properties file, but I don't want to overwrite every time the whole file, and if I try to use apache commons configuration, with setProperty, I can't put the value on the variables.

Which is the best way to store this kind of data?

Thank you all.

Comment: You can assign a timestamp to the user when they log in. If they hit remember me, just assign a time duration of like 1 day until it expires.

Comment: Instead of userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName()), you should be using `Preferences.userNodeForPackage(MyClass.class)`.  Always use a class literal (like `MyClass.class`) instead of getClass(), so inheritance won't cause the preferences to be stored in a place you didn't expect.

Comment: @piyush121 the problem is that I'm not able to preserve data when i close the application.

Comment: @VGR Tried, but it doesn't preserve data

Answer (score 0):

Yes preferences is really easy and good way of doing this , problem is that:

> he doesn't need to enter data next time

That means he WONT PUT ANYTHING INTO TEXT FIELDS.

> But if i close and reopen the app, if i print the content of
>   variables, it returns "Null key" NullPointerException.

What did you expected? You put this  NULL values into preferences again as he starts  his app again.

**Problem is in your design**

application starts->
read preference of checkbox state->
 {reread login credentials} else {nothing} ->
 show login ui , user enters credentials ->{compare credentials to whose with preferences}  DONT STORE ANYTHING , why woud you store what user is trying to  login with every single time you start application?

You only store credentials at user creation ,use encryption and   store your data, for both name , and password.

In your question there is not enough code to help you out directly with code sample , you have problem with design , where you reading this information in your code? Why dont you post this part here? You only show us that you store soemthing , well ok , thats useless to person thats trying to help you out.

I recommend you to SIT DOWN, stop writing code , and write yourslef flowchart of your application startup and login process all the way with when you read/write anything to preferences etc.